# write getter and setter method in c# with attributes

Tags: c#, modelattribute

I have a general code that i want using it for many string properties (when these properties set and get).

like this: (this is just an example)

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty
        {
            set
            {
                 //process
            }

            get
            {
                //process
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need: 
Can i write this code as attribute (For exmple: 'MyCustomAttribute') and just using this attribute for any string property that i need?

like this :

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        [MyCustomAttribute]
        public string MyProperty { set; get; }
    }


    public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
         // do setter and getter process here (whit methods)
    }
```

> Note: I dont want write this general code with extensions

Comment: Could you derive a type from string and define the processes there?

Comment: No, you'll need to add the code to each getter and setter. You can make it pretty painless though by adding backing fields and putting the functionality in Get/Set methods and then define your properties like: `public string MyProperty { get => Get(backingFieldName); set => Set(backingFieldName, value); }`

Comment: @Sami String is a sealed class. I think that will not work

Comment: @Marlonchosky good point..

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on the new source generators feature of roslyn at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md

This will help you auto generate properties based on attributes or any other pattern..